# Vue.js - displaying images rendered in API

Tags: c#, vue.js, swagger, .net-6.0

I have a Get method in an API that renders an image:

```
[HttpGet("GetImage/{userId}/{imageURL}")]
public IActionResult GetImage(string userId, string imageURL)
{
    byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("../WebServices/ImgLibrary/" + userId + "/" + imageURL);     
    return File(b, "image/png");
}
```

Now I need to call that method and display images in my Vue.js project, but I've been unable to get anything to render. This is my method for calling the API:

```
var imgURL = this.baseUrl + "/GetImage/" + user.Id.toString() + "/";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.imageList.length; i++) {
      imgURL += this.imageList[i].Name;
      const imgResponse = await fetch(imgURL,{
        method: "GET",
      });
      const thisImg = await imgResponse.blob();
      this.imgRawDataList[i] = thisImg
      imgURL = this.baseUrl + "/GetImage/" + user.Id.toString() + "/"; //reset
    }
```

This adds Blobs to the imgRawDataList array, which is a parallel array to the imageList array that stores the image paths. ImageK is a counter.

```
<div v-for="(ImageD, ImageK) in imageList">
  <div v-bind:data-src="ImageD.ImageUrl">
    <img v-bind:src="getRawURL(ImageD.ImageUrl, ImageK)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the getRawURL method to get the image src:

```
getRawURL(path, i) {
  if (this.imgRawDataList.length > 0) {
    if (this.imgRawDataList[i] !== undefined) {
      return 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(
        new Uint8Array(this.imgRawDataList[i])
        .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
      );   
    }
    else { return ''; }
  } else { return ''; } 
},
```

What comes back from the btoa method is nothing, so the images look like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64," data-v-30ae62="">
```

Are Blobs the best way to do this? In Swagger when testing my API the GetImage method will actually render the image, so I feel like I'm doing too much here.

Comment: When console logging the return from getRawURL, I get this back 6 times but I only have 3 images:          3 theReturn data:image/png;base64,

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? Looks like you could just put the URL into src. Also, I think you are putting a Uint8Array into btoa, but btoa takes a string.

Comment: The Image URLS are saved in the API project and the web app is a separate Vue.js application built in yarn. Both are currently using localhost URLs.